# Prove $\operatorname{dist}(\overline{A},\overline{B}) = \operatorname{dist}(A, B)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This is the last question on the exercise sheet and I am having real trouble formalizing my intuitions.

It should be obvious.  Since the closure of a set is the set of all points in the universe with distance zero to the set, then there should be no difference between finding the distance between the set and the distance between their closures (since zero is the additive identity). I feel like I could take advantage of the triangle inequality to formalize the picture in my head, but I can't seem to grasp it concretely.

Working Definitions:

$$ d(x, A) = \inf_{a \in A}\{d(x,a)\} $$
$$ \overline{A} = \{x \in X : d(x, A) = 0\} $$
$$ \operatorname{dist}(A, B) = \inf_{b \in B}\{d(b, A)\} $$

Comment: You probably want inf over $x\in B$ in the definition of dist$(A,B)$.

Comment: Right, thanks.  My brain is starting to mush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

**"$\leq$":** Since $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ and $B\subseteq \overline{B}$ then $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(a,b)$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$. Take infimum.

**"$\geq$":** Prove by triangle-inequality that for any $x,y\in X$ we have
\begin{equation*}
d(A,B)\leq d(A,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,B),
\end{equation*}
and conclude that for any $a\in\overline{A}$ and $b\in\overline{B}$ we have $d(A,B)\leq d(a,b)$. Take infimum.

Comment: I've been looking over this, but I don't see how we can say $d(\overline{A},\overline{B}) \leq d(a, b)$, whereas I *can* justify $d(\overline{A},\overline{B}) \leq d(A, B)$.  This is equivalent to taking the infimum over $a \in A, b \in B$, yes?

Comment: @vermiculus. The point is to show that $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(a,b)$ is true for all $a\in A,\,b\in B$. Thus, by taking infimum over all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ in this inequality, we obtain $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(A,B)$. But out of curiosity, how do you justify $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(A,B)$ without showing that $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(a,b)$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$?

Comment: $A \subset B \subset X \implies d(x \in B^\complement, A) \geq d(x \in B^\complement, B)$ (I'm not really sure how it follows from there, but that is my honest reasoning.  Brain dead.
My feeble mind understands the proof now, once I convinced myself that taking such an infimum is exactly the definition.  (Really, really brain dead.)

Comment: I know my way isn't the greatest (or even logical :P), but I think the professor said something to the effect of the result during lectures, but I can't find it in my notes.  Still have to prove that $d(\overline{A},\overline{B}) \leq d(a,b)$, correct?

Comment: @vermiculus. I'm not quite sure what you are after with that implication. You would have to justify it by using the definition, and thus infimum, anyways. And yes, the easiest way I see is just to show that $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(a,b)$ **for all** $a\in A$, $b\in B$ to conclude that $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(A,B)$.

And for the reverse inequality, you should show that $d(A,B)\leq d(a,b)$ **for all** $a\in \overline{A}$, $b\in\overline{B}$, to conclude that $d(A,B)\leq d(\overline{A},\overline{B})$.

Comment: sounds good to me. :)

Comment: @vermiculus. Great. Let me know if some points need further clarification.

Comment: I don't understand why "Since $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ and $B\subseteq \overline{B}$" implies " $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(a,b)$"

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo: Infimum is an increasing function when you decrease the set of which the infimum is taken over. The intuition is that the smaller set has at least the same infimum as the ambient set, but possibly larger in case you remove the smallest values of the set when creating the subset.